# Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR Error in Function

Tags: php

I'm getting Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in the Function below:

```
function _ip( )
{
    return ( preg_match( "/^([d]{1,3}).([d]{1,3}).([d]{1,3}).([d]{1,3})$/", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be using the getenv() method instead of $_SERVER.

```
function _ip( )
{
    if (preg_match( "/^([d]{1,3}).([d]{1,3}).([d]{1,3}).([d]{1,3})$/", getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    {
        return getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    }
    return getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
}
```

Also, I would stick with just `$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')` as spammers can set the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header themselves to anything they want while they can't change the remote_addr. The problem is that "good" proxies tell the truth about `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` so you would miss that.

Comment: Even though "good" proxies may be giving you a valid X-Forwarded-For, a lot of the values in those headers will be ones you don't want, like RFC1918 private IPs.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in C:\php_files\getip.php on line 7

Answer (score 3):

$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] doesn't exist in your array. You can confirm with `print_r($_SERVER)`. You'll need to test for the existence of that array index before using it.

```
function _ip( )
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        return ( preg_match( "/^([d]{1,3}).([d]{1,3}).([d]{1,3}).([d]{1,3})$/", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );
    } else {
        return null; //something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `` header present. You need to check to see if it's present before accessing it.

```
function _ip( )
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) {
        if (preg_match( "/^([d]{1,3}).([d]{1,3}).([d]{1,3}).([d]{1,3})$/", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
    }
    return isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it's because that index does not exist in the $_SERVER array.  You could avoid the notice by doing

```
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) { 
  // your code here
} else {
  if( isset( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) ) 
     return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  else  
    return FALSE;
}
```

I'm guessing you're trying to retrieve the remote address, the code above might be a bit more robust.

Comment: Hi, your answer missing the closing brackets here ```if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {// code here}```

Answer (score 0):

getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') returns false if the variable is not present in the $_SERVER array whereas $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] returns undefined index if the variable is not set.